# Redux: Filter data & rewind to initial data state in Reducer?

Tags: json, filter, redux, reducers

Let's say I have a large amount of JSON data that I want initially displayed on page load (working thus far) and the option to filter that data to show only a specific amount. When my `FILTER_DATA` action is dispatched, it checks the `view` property and executes helper functions to filter the array of data down to however much it is I need displayed.

*However... if I'm updating the state with the filtered version of the data and let's say the user wants to go back to the ORIGINAL view (the entire data set), is there a way to rewind state to that point?* I was considering re-dispatching the `FETCH_DATA` action to re-perform a GET request to fetch the data once again, but that seems obnoxious. Thoughts?
Below is my reducer:

**Note: `data` on the initialState object is an empty array value until `FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS` dispatches and sets `state.data` to the JSON data fetched in a GET request.**

```
const app = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA:
      return { ...state, error: '', loading: true };
    case FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, error: '', loading: false, data: action.data, view: 'all' };
    case FETCH_DATA_FAILURE:
      return { ...state, error: action.error, loading: false };
    case FILTER_DATA:
      let data;
      if (action.view === 'week') {
        data = groupData(getLastWeek(state.data), action.view);
      } else if (action.view === 'month') {
        data = groupData(getLastMonth(state.data), action.view);
      } else if (action.view === 'all') {
        data = state.data;
      }
      return { ...state, error: '', loading: false, data: data, view: view };
  }
  return state;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two main options.  First, if you really do want to keep the "filtered" data directly in your state, you could store two copies: the "original" and the "filtered" versions.

The other approach, which I recommend, is to keep both the original data and the filtering criteria in your state, but don't actually modify the original data.  Instead, derive the filtering outside of the store as needed.  This is a great use case for "selector functions".  See [Computing Derived Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) for some examples.

Comment: Hi .I am trying to go with approach one. But I am having difficulties keeping original one unchanged. Every time I apply a filter, original one changes too ..probably because Filtered one has reference of the original. I want to keep original one unchanged. How can I do that?

Comment: That sounds like you're mutating the original array in the process.  Don't do that :)